# WordPress custom post type queries

Tags: custom-post-types, query-posts

I'm using custom post types and listing them in single-[customposttype].php?type=example

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) :  the_post();the_content(); endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Now I have 2 different custom post type "customtype1" and "customtype2". "customtype1" is top category for "customtype2". When I add a new post on "customtype2" select category from metabox(I have a selectbox which listed "customtype1" posts.) in "customtype1" list. My question is how can I use a query for listing customtype2 posts which belongs top category page(single-customtype1.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This all depends on what you're actually saving in your post meta. If you're actually saving the ID you could create a secondary query on your `single-post_type.php` page.

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while( have_posts() ) :
            the_post();
            $cpt2_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_meta_name', true ); // Get out Post Type 2 Meta
    ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if( ! empty( $cpt2_meta ) ) :
    $cpt2_posts = new WP_Query( array( 
        'post_type' => 'cpt2_slug',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    ) );

    if( $cpt2_posts->have_posts() ) : 
?>
    <?php while( $cpt2_posts->have_posts() ) : $cpt2_posts->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile;?>
  <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

First we get the Post Meta ( category ) then we run a secondary query on that "category". Again, this may change depending on what you're saving as your post meta. For more information you can [read into WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Sorry but I need to be more specific. I have 2 custom post types lyrics and artists. In lyrics adding page I'm listing all artists(from artist custom post type) in select meta box. Now I need to list lyrics for specific artist. For example I want to just show rihanna's lyrics in single-{artistcustom}.php How can I use the query?

Comment: OK I found it..

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
<?php 
$id = get_the_ID();
$squery = new WP_Query( array( 
    'post_type' => 'lyrics',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key',
    'meta_value' => $id,
) );

if( $squery->have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while( $squery->have_posts() ) : $squery->the_post(); ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could that solve the problem?